# Apache2 only detects index.html instead of all files

Tags: apache2, html

I wanted to self-host a website and I cant find solution to this anywhere.
So, I have website files in /var/www/html but when I connect it only detects index.html
I tried to manually enter directory but it shows 404 even though it's there.

Comment: Have you confirmed the files are accessible to `www-data`? Are you running a static HTML site?

Comment: @matigo how can I check that?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Desktop or Server? The method you use to put the files in `/var/www/html` may also show you ownership / permission details 

Comment: I use desktop and the method I used to put files there was through mv command